# Override as_json method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to buid a blog app using rails api in backend and angular js in frontend.
In my app every post has many comments and every comment has many replies. I have made one to many relationship  between post  and comment and comment and replies. When I click on a  post title it takes me to a post show page using `PostController#show` method with it's comment. For this in Post model I have override `as_json` method like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  def as_json(options = {})
    super(options.merge(include: :comments))
  end
end
```

But I want to show all replies with the comment. For this how can I modify as_json method?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
posts.as_json(include: { comments: {
                           include: { replies: {
                                          only: :body } },
                           only: :title } })
```

[Ref](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html)

Comment: Yes, It's worked, I tried this way
   def as_json(options = {})
         super(options.merge(include: { comments: { include: :replies } } ))
 end

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please up vote and mark it as correct one :-)